# how to show this alphabetical scroll view in left side of the screen

Tags: android, scrollview

Here is the image URL for the alphabetical list view. I couldn't post it here as stackoverflow restricts me not having more reputations.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/hwg9g

How to show this alphabetical scrollview in the left side of the screen. I have got a sample application from internet for alphabetical scrollview and i have implemented with my project :-( As a beginner i do not understand their way of coding. They have used drawRoundRect method to draw this. I regret drawRoundRect and some paint stuffs are not familiar to me..!

```
public class IndexScroller {

private float mIndexbarWidth;
private float mIndexbarMargin;
private float mPreviewPadding;
private float mDensity;
private float mScaledDensity;
private float mAlphaRate;
private int mState = STATE_HIDDEN;
private int mListViewWidth;
private int mListViewHeight;
private int mCurrentSection = -1;
private boolean mIsIndexing = false;
private ListView mListView = null;
private SectionIndexer mIndexer = null;
private String[] mSections = null;
private RectF mIndexbarRect;

private static final int STATE_HIDDEN = 0;
private static final int STATE_SHOWING = 1;
private static final int STATE_SHOWN = 2;
private static final int STATE_HIDING = 3;

public IndexScroller(Context context, ListView lv) {
    mDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    mScaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    mListView = lv;
    setAdapter(mListView.getAdapter());

    mIndexbarWidth = 20 * mDensity;
    mIndexbarMargin = 10 * mDensity;
    mPreviewPadding = 5 * mDensity;
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mState == STATE_HIDDEN)
        return;

    // mAlphaRate determines the rate of opacity
    Paint indexbarPaint = new Paint();
    indexbarPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    indexbarPaint.setAlpha((int) (64 * mAlphaRate));
    indexbarPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(mIndexbarRect, 5 * mDensity, 5 * mDensity,
            indexbarPaint);

    if (mSections != null && mSections.length > 0) {
        // Preview is shown when mCurrentSection is set
        if (mCurrentSection >= 0) {
            Paint previewPaint = new Paint();
            previewPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            previewPaint.setAlpha(96);
            previewPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            previewPaint.setShadowLayer(3, 0, 0, Color.argb(64, 0, 0, 0));

            Paint previewTextPaint = new Paint();
            previewTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            previewTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            previewTextPaint.setTextSize(50 * mScaledDensity);

            float previewTextWidth = previewTextPaint
                    .measureText(mSections[mCurrentSection]);
            float previewSize = 2 * mPreviewPadding
                    + previewTextPaint.descent()
                    - previewTextPaint.ascent();

            RectF previewRect = new RectF(
                    (mListViewWidth - previewSize) / 2,
                    (mListViewHeight - previewSize) / 2,
                    (mListViewWidth - previewSize) / 2 + previewSize,
                    (mListViewHeight - previewSize) / 2 + previewSize);

            canvas.drawRoundRect(previewRect, 5 * mDensity, 5 * mDensity,
                    previewPaint);
            canvas.drawText(
                    mSections[mCurrentSection],
                    previewRect.left + (previewSize - previewTextWidth) / 2
                            - 1,
                    previewRect.top + mPreviewPadding
                            - previewTextPaint.ascent() + 1,
                    previewTextPaint);
        }

        Paint indexPaint = new Paint();
        indexPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        indexPaint.setAlpha((int) (255 * mAlphaRate));
        indexPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        indexPaint.setTextSize(12 * mScaledDensity);

        float sectionHeight = (mIndexbarRect.height() - 2 * mIndexbarMargin)
                / mSections.length;
        float paddingTop = (sectionHeight - (indexPaint.descent() - indexPaint
                .ascent())) / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < mSections.length; i++) {
            float paddingLeft = (mIndexbarWidth - indexPaint
                    .measureText(mSections[i])) / 2;

            canvas.drawText(mSections[i], mIndexbarRect.left + paddingLeft,
                    mIndexbarRect.top + mIndexbarMargin + sectionHeight * i
                            + paddingTop - indexPaint.ascent(), indexPaint);
        }
    }
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // If down event occurs inside index bar region, start indexing
        if (mState != STATE_HIDDEN && contains(ev.getX(), ev.getY())) {
            setState(STATE_SHOWN);

            // It demonstrates that the motion event started from index bar
            mIsIndexing = true;
            // Determine which section the point is in, and move the list to
            // that section
            mCurrentSection = getSectionByPoint(ev.getY());
            mListView.setSelection(mIndexer
                    .getPositionForSection(mCurrentSection));
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mIsIndexing) {
            // If this event moves inside index bar
            if (contains(ev.getX(), ev.getY())) {
                // Determine which section the point is in, and move the
                // list to that section
                mCurrentSection = getSectionByPoint(ev.getY());
                mListView.setSelection(mIndexer
                        .getPositionForSection(mCurrentSection));
            }
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (mIsIndexing) {
            mIsIndexing = false;
            mCurrentSection = -1;
        }
        if (mState == STATE_SHOWN)
            setState(STATE_HIDING);
        break;
    }
    return false;
}

public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    mListViewWidth = w;
    mListViewHeight = h;
    mIndexbarRect = new RectF(w - mIndexbarMargin - mIndexbarWidth,
            mIndexbarMargin, w - mIndexbarMargin, h - mIndexbarMargin);
}

public void show() {
    if (mState == STATE_HIDDEN)
        setState(STATE_SHOWING);
    else if (mState == STATE_HIDING)
        setState(STATE_HIDING);
}

public void hide() {
    if (mState == STATE_SHOWN)
        setState(STATE_HIDING);
}

public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
    if (adapter instanceof SectionIndexer) {
        mIndexer = (SectionIndexer) adapter;
        mSections = (String[]) mIndexer.getSections();
    }
}

private void setState(int state) {
    if (state < STATE_HIDDEN || state > STATE_HIDING)
        return;

    mState = state;
    switch (mState) {
    case STATE_HIDDEN:
        // Cancel any fade effect
        mHandler.removeMessages(0);
        break;
    case STATE_SHOWING:
        // Start to fade in
        mAlphaRate = 0;
        fade(0);
        break;
    case STATE_SHOWN:
        // Cancel any fade effect
        mHandler.removeMessages(0);
        break;
    case STATE_HIDING:
        // Start to fade out after three seconds
        mAlphaRate = 1;
        fade(5000);
        break;
    }
}

private boolean contains(float x, float y) {
    // Determine if the point is in index bar region, which includes the
    // right margin of the bar
    return (x >= mIndexbarRect.left && y >= mIndexbarRect.top && y <= mIndexbarRect.top
            + mIndexbarRect.height());
}

private int getSectionByPoint(float y) {
    if (mSections == null || mSections.length == 0)
        return 0;
    if (y < mIndexbarRect.top + mIndexbarMargin)
        return 0;
    if (y >= mIndexbarRect.top + mIndexbarRect.height() - mIndexbarMargin)
        return mSections.length - 1;
    return (int) ((y - mIndexbarRect.top - mIndexbarMargin) / ((mIndexbarRect
            .height() - 2 * mIndexbarMargin) / mSections.length));
}

private void fade(long delay) {
    mHandler.removeMessages(0);
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(0, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + delay);
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        switch (mState) {
        case STATE_SHOWING:
            // Fade in effect
            mAlphaRate += (1 - mAlphaRate) * 0.2;
            if (mAlphaRate > 0.9) {
                mAlphaRate = 1;
                setState(STATE_SHOWN);
            }

            mListView.invalidate();
            fade(10);
            break;
        case STATE_SHOWN:
            // If no action, hide automatically
            setState(STATE_HIDING);
            break;
        case STATE_HIDING:
            // Fade out effect
            mAlphaRate -= mAlphaRate * 0.2;
            if (mAlphaRate < 0.1) {
                mAlphaRate = 0;
                setState(STATE_HIDDEN);
            }

            mListView.invalidate();
            fade(10);
            break;
        }
    }

};


It would be really nice if you help me to show this alphabetical scroll bar in the left side of the screen.
```

Comment: [Have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8192683/940096)

Comment: @ Praveen, Thanks for responding my query.. i have downloaded the above alphabetical scrollview from the link you mentioned only.. [here is the link](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView/blob/master/src/com/woozzu/android/widget/IndexScroller.java) but how can i show alphabetical scroll view in the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got that this way,

```
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    mListViewWidth = w;
    mListViewHeight = h;

    mIndexbarRect = new RectF(mIndexbarMargin, mIndexbarMargin,
            mIndexbarMargin + mIndexbarWidth, h - mIndexbarMargin);
}
```

This is the method to draw the rectangle in left side of the screen.

```
   private boolean contains(float x, float y) {

    return (x <= mIndexbarRect.right && y >= mIndexbarRect.top && y <= mIndexbarRect.top
            + mIndexbarRect.height());
}
```

It will work smoothly if you change the function to the below. sorry for the posting this answer little late.

please check out : [Indexable list view](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView/blob/master/src/com/woozzu/android/widget/IndexScroller.java)