# Alphabetical scrolling in android

Tags: android, scroll, scrollbar, scrollview, android-scrollview

I know this question has been repeated several times here on SO. I've gone through almost all of 'em. Out of all those, I finally implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192683/how-to-create-an-alphabetical-scrollbar-displaying-all-the-letter-in-android) solution. Now this seems to work alright. But it requires onClick event while I want it to be onTouch. Now it was easy to define onClick function for 26 text views but I see no such option for onTouch event. Can anyone please help? I'm very new to this thing.

Also, 26 text views don't fit on 1 screen. I could define their size for different screen sizes but I donno how to do that collectively for 26 text views. I followed exactly that solution (link above) & this is my style attribute for my text views

```
<style name="alphabetTextView" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">onClick</item>
</style>
```

Please help as I want to create same alphabetical scrolling as iPhones. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why exactly do you want onTouch over onClick

Comment: For onClick I've to click but what I want it to respond it onTouch.

Comment: So just set it in your java instead with setOnTouchListener()

Comment: Yeah, that is the point. I don't want to define onTouch for 26 text views in my Java code. Can't I have something similar as above?

Comment: like I've defined onClick method for onClick event. because otherwise I'll have to first identify 26 text views & then implement their onTouch listener.

Comment: I've this one more question. Is there any way to change the android:height attribute in my style alphabetTextView because otherwise I'll have to identify 26 textview again using findViewById making the code really messy.