# how to show an alphabetical scrollview on the right side of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, view, scroll

I am trying to create a an alphabetical scrollview to be diplayed on the right side of a listview to enable quick scrolling.i have done as instructed from this question 
[How to create an alphabetical scrollbar displaying all the letter in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192683/how-to-create-an-alphabetical-scrollbar-displaying-all-the-letter-in-android/21363790#21363790)

i have followed the above steps but on clicking the letters nothing happens,kindly assist.here's my code

**java**

```
  public void quickScroll(View v) {
    String firstLetter = (String) v.getTag();
   int index = 0;

   List<String> s=Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O",
           "P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");
    if (s != null) {
        for (String string : s) {
            if (string.startsWith(firstLetter)) {
                index = s.indexOf(string);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    lv.setSelectionFromTop(index, 0);
    //lv is my listview
}
```

and the **xml** below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
   android:id="@+id/lv"/>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/A" android:text="A" android:tag="A" 
       android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"

       />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/B" android:text="B" android:tag="B"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
        />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/C" android:text="C" android:tag="C"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
     />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/D" android:text="D" android:tag="D"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/E" android:text="E" android:tag="E"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/F" android:text="F" android:tag="F"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
        />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/G" android:text="G" android:tag="G"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/H" android:text="H" android:tag="H"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/I" android:text="I" android:tag="I"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/J" android:text="J" android:tag="J"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/K" android:text="K" android:tag="K"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/L" android:text="L" android:tag="L"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
        />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/M" android:text="M" android:tag="M"
         android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
        />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/N" android:text="N" android:tag="N"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/O" android:text="O" android:tag="O"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
      />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/P" android:text="P" android:tag="P"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
        />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/Q" android:text="Q" android:tag="Q"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/R" android:text="R" android:tag="R"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/S" android:text="S" android:tag="S"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
    />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/T" android:text="T" android:tag="T"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/U" android:text="U" android:tag="U"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/V" android:text="V" android:tag="V"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
        />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/W" android:text="W" android:tag="W"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
        />
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/X" android:text="X" android:tag="X"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
        />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Y" android:text="Y" android:tag="Y"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
       />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Z" android:text="Z" android:tag="Z"
          android:clickable="true"  android:onClick="quickScroll"
        />

</LinearLayout>
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:text="Done" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

@bloodyshadow i am just asking you to apply `OnClickListener` on *TextViews* first you apply that it will work

you were using `onClick attribute` in xml that not work fine with that

Comment: Better you can comment rather than putting answers http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

you can solve this issue by apply "OnCLickListener" in java class
xml onClick not working here

Comment: Do not post single line answer. Add some codes too.

Comment: TextView text=findViewById(R.id.textid)

text.SetOnClickLintener( new OnClickListener(){

     OnClick(View v){
}

});