# Android alphabetical fast scrollview in RecyclerView with Collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, fastscroll

In my application I have activity_main.xml like this:-

```
<Coordinator Layout>
   <AppBarLayout>
      <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
           <ImageView/>
           <Toolbar/>
       </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
   </AppBarLayout>
   <RecyclerView/>
</Coordinating Layout>
```

Layout.xml ----->>>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/theme_background"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    >


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_id"
        tools:context="objectdistance.ajai.ram.sita.gallery.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imagetoolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:foreground="@drawable/image_header_foreground"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    android:background="@drawable/theme_background"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="?attr/actionBarSize" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />




    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navlist"
        android:background="#dedede"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now I want to include fast scrolling to my recyclerview such that the image date can be popup on scrolling.

Sample image of such scrollbar:-
[image: Scrolling]

I searched for this and tried using few libraries but I think due to my collapsing toolbar the scrollbar is not working properly.

Screenshot of scroll Library used:-
[image: My device]

Here in my case the scroll bar is starting from top and the scroll computation is also not proper.

Please help solving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: did you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192683/how-to-create-an-alphabetical-scrollbar-displaying-all-the-letter-in-android

Comment: sorry, but without full xml code I can only advise you to search for `alphabetical scrollview`

Comment: @piotrek1543 I used some external fastscroll library for this. But now I think I need to create scroller  by myself. So please if you can tell me how to start

Comment: xml layout file please ;-)

Comment: @piotrek1543 I have updated my layout.xml code

Comment: @Ankesh...Which library are you using?

Comment: Currently I am not using any ibrary. I tried using 2-3 libraries but had same issue.

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria well where  are you are placing your scrollBar??In your code ??Try to implement the whole scrollbar logic in a CoordinatorLayout behavior.

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria well I found the open source library material scrollbar the one u want to have a finality like?? have u tried implementing scrollbar with this library?? And is there any error or warnings when u debug this code ??please post your logcat if so??

Comment: @PN10 Which library?.. please add link to the library you are talking about.

Comment: here you go https://github.com/turing-tech/MaterialScrollBar ...the one u  have a fxnality like

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria see this issue also if u want to work with this library  https://github.com/turing-tech/MaterialScrollBar/issues/20

Comment: fxnality like ??????????

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria scrolling functionality??

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria     As far as i understand you want to have an alphabetical scrollview functionality like MaterialScrollBar library isn't it??

Comment: I tried using this library but I think not able to get things properly. In this library the issue is that it is made for LinearLayout  and mine is GridLayout

Comment: I would still like to reward bounty . I dont know how can I do that in comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121469/discussion-between-pn10-and-ankesh-kumar-jaisansaria).

Comment: Do you have 2 accounts? Or did a relative of yours start the bounty?

Comment: I dont have two accounts and the person who started bounty is not my relative. There is no point of doubt if some other person starts bounty on an exisiting question.

Answer (score 14):

we want **some Knowledge** of `SectionIndexer`. Here is [Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html) of **SectionIndexer**.

We have to **set TRUE** `setFastScrollEnabled(true)` method, which is **used with the `LISTVIEW`**.......You can use `recyclerview` instead of `listView` in the below example....

this is activity

```
public class FastScoll extends ListActivity {

    ListView fruitView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fast_scoll);

        fruitView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        fruitView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        String[] fruits = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruits_array);

        final List<String> fruitList = Arrays.asList(fruits);
        Collections.sort(fruitList);
        setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, fruitList));

        fruitView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                                    int position, long arg3) {
                Log.e("sushildlh",fruitList.get(position));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

this is the activity_fast_scoll.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my custom adapter with `SectionIndexer`....

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements SectionIndexer {

    String[] sections;
    List<String> fruits;
    List<String> sectionLetters=new ArrayList<String>();

    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<String> fruitList) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fruitList);
        this.fruits = fruitList;

        for (int x = 0; x < fruits.size(); x++) {
            String fruit = fruits.get(x);
            String ch = fruit.charAt(0)+"";
            ch = ch.toUpperCase(Locale.US);

            sectionLetters.add(ch);
        }

        ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);

        sections = new String[sectionList.size()];

        sectionList.toArray(sections);
    }

    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {

        Log.e("sushildlh", "" + section);
        return section;
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {

        Log.d("sushildlh", "" + position);
        return position;
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {
        return sections;
    }
}
```

this is fruits array in string.xml file.

```
 <string-array name="fruits_array">
            <item>Apples</item>
            <item>Apricots</item>
            <item>Avocado</item>
            <item>Annona</item>
            <item>Banana</item>
            <item>Bilberry</item>
            <item>Blackberry</item>
            <item>Custard Apple</item>
            <item>Clementine</item>
            <item>Cantalope</item>
            <item>Coconut</item>
            <item>Currant</item>
            <item>Cherry</item>
            <item>Cherimoya</item>
            <item>Date</item>
            <item>Damson</item>
            <item>Durian</item>
            <item>Elderberry</item>
            <item>Fig</item>
            <item>Feijoa</item>
            <item>Grapefruit</item>
            <item>Grape</item>
            <item>Gooseberry</item>
            <item>Guava</item>
            <item>Honeydew melon</item>
            <item>Huckleberry</item>
            <item>Jackfruit</item>
            <item>Juniper Berry</item>
            <item>Jambul</item>
            <item>Jujube</item>
            <item>Kiwi</item>
            <item>Kumquat</item>
            <item>Lemons</item>
            <item>Limes</item>
            <item>Lychee</item>
            <item>Mango</item>
            <item>Mandarin</item>
            <item>Mangostine</item>
            <item>Nectaraine</item>
            <item>Orange</item>
            <item>Olive</item>
            <item>Prunes</item>
            <item>Pears</item>
            <item>Plum</item>
            <item>Pineapple</item>
            <item>Peach</item>
            <item>Papaya</item>
            <item>Passionfruit</item>
            <item>Pomegranate</item>
            <item>Pomelo</item>
            <item>Raspberries</item>
            <item>Rock melon</item>
            <item>Rambutan</item>
            <item>Strawberries</item>
            <item>Sweety</item>
            <item>Salmonberry</item>
            <item>Satsuma</item>
            <item>Tangerines</item>
            <item>Tomato</item>
            <item>Ugli</item>
            <item>Watermelon</item>
            <item>Woodapple</item>
        </string-array>
```

and finally this is the output of the these code....

[image: o][image: o1][image: o2]

**Feel free to ask if you stuck anywhere in between code ....**

**Note:- FastScroll image will be differ in different version of android (eg:-lollipop,marshmallow,etc) below output is for lollipop**

[image: lollipop]

For **Custom Alphabetical Fast scrollView** just add these 2 line in your `style.xml` file in `AppTheme`.

```
<item name="android:fastScrollTextColor">@color/apptheme_color</item>         //this is used for the color of the Alphabetical Fast scrollView
<item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/bg_default_focused_holo_light</item>          //this is the image or and drawable file you want to set on Alphabetical Fast scrollView
```

**Custom Fast Scorll Output :-**

[image: ouy]

Comment: setFastScrollEnabled is not available in recyclerview

Comment: @Nainal above example with listView.

Comment: For those who r facing with recyclerview settign programmatically, set it through xml: 
` app:fastScrollEnabled="true"`

Comment: for recycler view check this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46026362/5664529

Answer (score 3):

There is a good library [here](https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller) with this [example](https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller/tree/master/Application). Also there is a good tutorial  [here](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/recyclerview-fastscroll-part-2/#comment-67201) with this example in [Github](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/LollipopContactsRecyclerViewFastScroller).

Usage:

make a RecyclerView.Adapter that implements BubbleTextGetter, which given a position in the data will return the text to show in the bubble-popup.
position the FastScroller inside the layout that container the RecyclerView (probably at the right area).

Customize the FastScroller some disadvantages:

doesn't support orientation change, but it's probably easy to fix.
doesn't support other layoutManagers. Only LinearLayoutManager
Needs API 11 and above.

Code:

BubbleTextGetter

```
public interface BubbleTextGetter
  {
  String getTextToShowInBubble(int pos);
  }
```

recycler_view_fast_scroller__fast_scroller.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/fastscroller_bubble"
    android:layout_gravity="right|end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="48sp" tools:text="A"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFffffff"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/recycler_view_fast_scroller__bubble"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fastscroller_handle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/recycler_view_fast_scroller__handle"/>

</merge>
```

Now this ScrollListener:

```
private class ScrollListener extends OnScrollListener
    {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView rv,int dx,int dy)
      {
      View firstVisibleView=recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
      int firstVisiblePosition=recyclerView.getChildPosition(firstVisibleView);
      int visibleRange=recyclerView.getChildCount();
      int lastVisiblePosition=firstVisiblePosition+visibleRange;
      int itemCount=recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
      int position;
      if(firstVisiblePosition==0)
        position=0;
      else if(lastVisiblePosition==itemCount-1)
        position=itemCount-1;
      else
        position=firstVisiblePosition;
      float proportion=(float)position/(float)itemCount;
      setPosition(height*proportion);
      }
    }
  }
```

This custom LinearLayout:

```
public class FastScroller extends LinearLayout
  {
  private static final int BUBBLE_ANIMATION_DURATION=100;
  private static final int TRACK_SNAP_RANGE=5;

  private TextView bubble;
  private View handle;
  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private final ScrollListener scrollListener=new ScrollListener();
  private int height;

  private ObjectAnimator currentAnimator=null;

  public FastScroller(final Context context,final AttributeSet attrs,final int defStyleAttr)
    {
    super(context,attrs,defStyleAttr);
    initialise(context);
    }

  public FastScroller(final Context context)
    {
    super(context);
    initialise(context);
    }

  public FastScroller(final Context context,final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
    super(context,attrs);
    initialise(context);
    }

  private void initialise(Context context)
    {
    setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
    setClipChildren(false);
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_fast_scroller__fast_scroller,this,true);
    bubble=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fastscroller_bubble);
    handle=findViewById(R.id.fastscroller_handle);
    bubble.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }

  @Override
  protected void onSizeChanged(int w,int h,int oldw,int oldh)
    {
    super.onSizeChanged(w,h,oldw,oldh);
    height=h;
    }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event)
    {
    final int action=event.getAction();
    switch(action)
      {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(event.getX()<handle.getX())
          return false;
        if(currentAnimator!=null)
          currentAnimator.cancel();
        if(bubble.getVisibility()==INVISIBLE)
          showBubble();
        handle.setSelected(true);
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        setPosition(event.getY());
        setRecyclerViewPosition(event.getY());
        return true;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        handle.setSelected(false);
        hideBubble();
        return true;
      }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

  public void setRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {
    this.recyclerView=recyclerView;
    recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    }

  private void setRecyclerViewPosition(float y)
    {
    if(recyclerView!=null)
      {
      int itemCount=recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
      float proportion;
      if(handle.getY()==0)
        proportion=0f;
      else if(handle.getY()+handle.getHeight()>=height-TRACK_SNAP_RANGE)
        proportion=1f;
      else
        proportion=y/(float)height;
      int targetPos=getValueInRange(0,itemCount-1,(int)(proportion*(float)itemCount));
      recyclerView.scrollToPosition(targetPos);
      String bubbleText=((BubbleTextGetter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).getTextToShowInBubble(targetPos);
      bubble.setText(bubbleText);
      }
    }

  private int getValueInRange(int min,int max,int value)
    {
    int minimum=Math.max(min,value);
    return Math.min(minimum,max);
    }

  private void setPosition(float y)
    {
    int bubbleHeight=bubble.getHeight();
    int handleHeight=handle.getHeight();
    handle.setY(getValueInRange(0,height-handleHeight,(int)(y-handleHeight/2)));
    bubble.setY(getValueInRange(0,height-bubbleHeight-handleHeight/2,(int)(y-bubbleHeight)));
    }

  private void showBubble()
    {
    AnimatorSet animatorSet=new AnimatorSet();
    bubble.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    if(currentAnimator!=null)
      currentAnimator.cancel();
    currentAnimator=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bubble,"alpha",0f,1f).setDuration(BUBBLE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    currentAnimator.start();
    }

  private void hideBubble()
    {
    if(currentAnimator!=null)
      currentAnimator.cancel();
    currentAnimator=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bubble,"alpha",1f,0f).setDuration(BUBBLE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    currentAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
    {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
      {
      super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
      bubble.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
      currentAnimator=null;
      }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
      {
      super.onAnimationCancel(animation);
      bubble.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
      currentAnimator=null;
      }
    });
    currentAnimator.start();
    }
```

The last step in your activity `onCreate`:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView recyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.activity_main_recyclerview);


    FastScroller fastScroller=(FastScroller)findViewById(R.id.fastscroller);
    fastScroller.setRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/theme_background"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_id"
        tools:context="objectdistance.ajai.ram.sita.gallery.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imagetoolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:foreground="@drawable/image_header_foreground"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    android:background="@drawable/theme_background"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="?attr/actionBarSize" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_main_height"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: what about displaying selected item's text

Comment: @AkashDubey can check this [example in GitHub](https://github.com/thedeveloperworldisyours/FullRecyclerView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/thedeveloperworldisyours/fullrecycleview/updateData).

Answer (score 1):

**To achieve something similar to the contact list of phone or same like the image given in the question which have text and image both, [This](https://github.com/timusus/RecyclerView-FastScroll) is the BEST solution I came across!**

This will work with **the custom list** as Images may need to be there with the name. Above solutions only have the list or array of String which may not everyone need!

**Only 3 Easy Steps:**

**1.** add dependency `implementation 'com.simplecityapps:recyclerview-fastscroll:2.0.1'`

**2.** Replace your `RecyclerView` with `com.simplecityapps.recyclerview_fastscroll.views.FastScrollRecyclerView`

**3.** implement `FastScrollRecyclerView.SectionedAdapter` in your recyclerview adapter

and done!