# How to use fastScrollEnabled in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to RecyclerView and I want to implement the fast scroll feature in RecyclerView like google contact application and search on the internet and i found that now Android provide officially New `fastScrollEnabled` boolean flag for RecyclerView. So my question is can someone provide the sample implementation of it.

Here is the official document from google
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0

Comment: follow this link [RecyclerViewFastScroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798212/how-to-add-a-fast-scroller-to-the-recyclerview)

Comment: @NileshRathod Thank you for your reply but i want to do without using any third party library.

Comment: in that link there is many custom available

Comment: @CHANDANSHARMA check my answer

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With Support Library 26, we can easily enable fast scrolling for RecyclerView. Let’s get to it!

Let’s go over each property one by one:

1. **fastScrollEnabled** : boolean value to enable the fast scrolling. Setting this as true will require that we provide the following four
   properties.
2. **fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable** : A StateListDrawable that will be used to draw the thumb which will be draggable across the
   horizontal axis.
3. **fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable** : A StateListDrawable that will be used to draw the line that will represent the scrollbar on
   horizontal axis.
4. **fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable** : A StateListDrawable that will be used to draw the thumb which will be draggable on vertical axis.
5. **fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable** : A StateListDrawable that will be used to draw the line that will represent the scrollbar on
   vertical axis.

In case someone is not aware of the names of each part of a Scrollbar, here is a image showing it:

[image: An image of a grey enable vertical Scroll Bar, displaying the that the track is the area bellow the two arrows of the scrollbar and the Thumb is the element that runs inside the track as the user scroll the scrollbar]

**Source:** [Make your website stand out with a custom scrollbar](https://blog.esteetey.dev/make-your-website-stand-out-with-a-custom-scrollbar)

---

add in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
}
```

Since Support Library 26 has now been moved to Google’s maven repository, let’s include that in our project level **build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
    app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
    app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable">
    
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

add below four xml file in your drawable folder,

**line_drawable.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/line"/>
    
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/line"/>
</selector>
```

**line.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    
    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    
    <padding
        android:top="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

**thumb_drawable.xml**

```

**thumb.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">
    
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="44dp"
        android:topRightRadius="44dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="44dp" />
    
    <padding
        android:paddingLeft="22dp"
        android:paddingRight="22dp" />
   
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    
</shape>
```

Comment: I followed your example, but my view is not scrolling fast, only when I am touching the thumb. But the thumb is so small and often I can´t touch it. Is this normal?

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/fast-scrolling-with-recyclerview-2b89d4574688 . May be this is a blog from where the answer is given.

Comment: The small thumb is a known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64729576  Unfortunately it's been six months and no sign of a fix :(

Comment: I've tried this but how to show text that moves along scrollbar when I scroll the list like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMh1q.png

Comment: Any way to set those programmatically?

Comment: Currently, there is no way to set it programmatically.

Comment: `app:fastScrollEnabled="true"` causes Error `android.view.InflateException` with AndroidX

Comment: @KintanPatel what the `padding` tag on the `thumb.xml` file does? For me, if I remove it, I don't see any difference. In my case, I'm implementing androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0 library in my project.

Answer (score 12):

Add the attributes to the `RecyclerView` tag in your layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_thumb"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_track"
    app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_thumb"
    app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_track"
/>
```

Make two drawables. The "track" drawable can be any drawable, but the "thumb" drawable must be a state list drawable.

Example `drawable/fast_scroll_track.xml` file:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#80ffffff" />
</shape>
```

Example `drawable/fast_scroll_thumb.xml` file:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff0" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 4):

As you know that, RecyclerView supports “fast scroller” in Support Library 26.0.0.

> **Note:** Keep in mind it’s XML-only though.

[image: usage]

Comment: How do you add a letter to the thumb? Or is that not supported in support library's fast scroller?

Comment: It's not supported to add letter

Answer (score 3):

**For an eye candy scroll bar thumb(round borders) :**

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/netflixVideoGridView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_thumb"
                app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_track"
                app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_thumb"
                app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_track"
                 />
```

**fast_scroll_thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/thumb"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/thumb"/>
</selector>
```

**thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:radius="50dp" />

    <padding
        android:paddingLeft="22dp"
        android:paddingRight="22dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#69f0ae" />

</shape>
```

**track.xml:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#80ffffff" />
    <padding
        android:padding="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

**Result:**

[image]