# android.widget.Scroller add fast scroll behaviour

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-recyclerview, scroller

How can I enable **fast scroll behaviour** for **`android.widget.Scroller`**? I have **`android.widget.Scroller`** working fine but I want to achieve fast scrolling behavior like in recycle view. I am not using `RecycleView` I am drawing in canvas.

Comment: You can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370246/how-to-use-fastscrollenabled-in-recyclerview).

Comment: I am not using recycleview.

Comment: Can you post some code that cause a problem?

Comment: It is not a problem. I am asking is it even possible to create fast scroll behavior for android.widget.Scroller