How to implement fast scroll on recyclerview Android Studio kotlin
I have an wallpaper app with a recyclerview that displays data from Firebase Realtime Database. That app gets loaded with images every few weeks and would like to add a fast scroll to make the user experience more bearable as the number of images increase in the recyclerview. I have tried other solutions, but they are very outdated and some are just outright unhelpful.
This is my XML code
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.PhonePapers"
    tools:context=".AbstractWallpapers">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/abstract_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:fastScrollEnabled="true"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/abstract_subscribe_btn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/subscribe"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:cornerRadius="150dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/orange"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


There's only one way to enable the built-in fast-scroll on RecyclerView, so if that's what you're trying to turn on, then it doesn't really matter that the posts are outdated; it's still the same method it's always been. This one seems to cover everything: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46026362. If you're having specific issues, please provide more details.

Thank you mike for the link. I couldn't find those solutions before. Others were giving issues because of wrong classes or dependencies.

Ah, OK, yeah, that one was written while RecyclerView was part of the old support library, but aside from the dependency and the package name, the rest of it should all be the same. The current versions tag would be <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>, and you might already have the right dependency, since most projects include it by default nowadays. I forget that not everyone was around for the library switchover, so many don't realize that android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView is just the old name for it.
