# Recycler Items with Indicator

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My need is That I am inflating JSON data in Recycler. okay. Now I want to put a indicator [LIKE THIS STYLE](https://github.com/viethoa/image-repositories/blob/master/fastcsrcolleralphabet.gif) that will show that how many items you have in RecyclerView. When one item has been readed  or currently, Indicator will be heilighted and when use scroll down the its top selected position item will be heilighted.. Please help me how can I do this..

**My Adapter Method**

```
     @Override
    public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_message, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        /*Tuesday, April 10, 2001 3:51 PM*/

        msgModels = msgList.get(position);
        if (msgList.get(position) != null) {

                holder.msgTitle.setText(msgModels.getMessageTitle());
                holder.msgDescription.setText(msgModels.getMessageDescription());
                holder.msgDate.setText(msgModels.getMessageDate());
//

        }

        if (firstVisible==position) {
            holder.msgTitle.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.msgDescription.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.msgDate.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.layerLyt.setAlpha(1);
        }

        if (position==msgList.size()-1) {
            holder.msgTitle.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.msgDescription.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.msgDate.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.layerLyt.setAlpha(1);
        }
        else{
            holder.msgTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            holder.msgDescription.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            holder.msgDate.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            holder.layerLyt.setAlpha(0.2f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return msgList.size();
    }

    private int firstVisible = 0;
    private int lastVisible ;

    public void changeItem(int position){
        firstVisible = position;
        notifyItemChanged(firstVisible);
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }  public void changeLastItem(int position){
        lastVisible = position;
        notifyItemChanged(lastVisible);
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView msgTitle, msgDescription,msgDate;
        public RelativeLayout layerLyt;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            msgTitle  = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.msgTitle);
            msgDescription  = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.msgDescription);
            layerLyt = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layerLyt);
            msgDate  = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.msgDate);
        }
    }
```

**My Fragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, null);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_viewLaws);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(msgAdapter);
    msgAdapter = new MessageAdapter(msgList, getActivity(), this);


    //msgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

            int firstVisible = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastVisible = manager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            Log.i("TAG", "onScrolled: " + firstVisible);
            Log.i("TAG", "Last Index: " + lastVisible);
            msgAdapter.changeItem(firstVisible);
            msgAdapter.changeLastItem(lastVisible);
        }
    });


    if (NetworkCheck.getInstant(getActivity()).isConnectingToInternet()) {
        loadAPI();
    } else {
        ErrorMessageDialog.getInstant(getActivity()).show("No Network");
    }
    return view;
}

private void loadAPI() {
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();
    new PostStringRequest(getActivity(), setMessagePostBody(), this, API_MSG_CALL, NetworkUtility.MESSAGE_API);
}
```

Comment: Did you even try to search about it using the name in the link you put ? [maybe this?](https://github.com/viethoa/fast-scroller-alphabet-android)

Comment: Yes I tried... but no luck

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192683/how-to-create-an-alphabetical-scrollbar-displaying-all-the-letter-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement by using third party library

https://github.com/andraskindler/quickscroll

Comment: Can I convert Alphabet Indicator to number based on out List Items ?